# Какой IP из заголовков письма использовать для проверки в блеклистах?

Tags: email, спам, spamassasin

Стоит задача проверить IP адрес отправителя по блек-листам. Письмо проходит цепочку MTA серверов, после чего оказывается во входящих. Вопрос в том, какой IP проверять?

Например, это письмо "снято" с моего почтового сервера Exim, имеет такие заголовки:

```
From start@speed24.ru Fri Aug 02 13:38:07 2019
Return-path: <start@speed24.ru>
Envelope-to: 5d443c9882cd8e56734b18e9@spam24.ru
Delivery-date: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 13:38:07 +0000
Received: from forward101o.mail.yandex.net ([37.140.190.181])
    by spam24.ru with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.92)
    (envelope-from <start@speed24.ru>)
    id 1htXl1-0000hE-G1
    for 5d443c9882cd8e56734b18e9@spam24.ru; Fri, 02 Aug 2019 13:38:07 +0000
Received: from mxback23g.mail.yandex.net (mxback23g.mail.yandex.net [IPv6:2a02:6b8:0:1472:2741:0:8b7:323])
    by forward101o.mail.yandex.net (Yandex) with ESMTP id 215743C02803
    for <5d443c9882cd8e56734b18e9@spam24.ru>; Fri,  2 Aug 2019 16:38:07 +0300 (MSK)
Received: from localhost (localhost [::1])
    by mxback23g.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTP id D9c0gGzRUt-c6gqqJr9;
    Fri, 02 Aug 2019 16:38:06 +0300
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=speed24.ru; s=mail; t=1564753086;
    bh=6cZYSCXHXapH0wa6EedMXzSSIua6AI+5MEmf9RXvraM=;
    h=Message-Id:Date:Subject:To:From;
    b=JxZ0hm4f8XsnFdcL2KH4+9JbixE9cqE51hyrOak5vu7pbm5SPUA6UhYseYJttEvoR
     Be82cx6HBwh66u661s4XFZOiKUSgnWK+6LavZ6cuCjAVqLYTsoOL0j2MCMbwqBIrrD
     RglkWBUTOd5wE/YvzcNP4MB+zwzgdIz55e1xZBBI=
Authentication-Results: mxback23g.mail.yandex.net; dkim=pass header.i=@speed24.ru
Received: by sas2-3b71b6ddd4dd.qloud-c.yandex.net with HTTP;
    Fri, 02 Aug 2019 16:38:06 +0300
From: start@speed24.ru
To: 5d443c9882cd8e56734b18e9@spam24.ru
```

После поиска по `Received: from` получается такая цепочка:

```
Received: from forward101o.mail.yandex.net ([37.140.190.181])
Received: from mxback23g.mail.yandex.net (mxback23g.mail.yandex.net [IPv6:2a02:6b8:0:1472:2741:0:8b7:323])
Received: from localhost (localhost [::1])
```

Последним в этой цепочке оказался `37.140.190.181`, который и нужно проверять на блек-листы?

Другое письмо, я взял его с почты yandex.ru:

```
Received: from mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net with LMTP id hjem9177u9-0iu6qjZz
    for <mail@yandex.ru>; Tue, 26 Nov 2019 07:57:38 +0300
Received: from 176147.simplecloud.ru (176147.simplecloud.ru [85.143.216.132])
    by mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net (mxfront/Yandex) with ESMTP id NqorZasIiC-vbv8Aue2;
    Tue, 26 Nov 2019 07:57:37 +0300
Return-Path: noreply@glavclub.com
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1574744257.898
Authentication-Results: mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net; spf=pass (mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net: domain of glavclub.com designates 85.143.216.132 as permitted sender, rule=[ip4:85.143.216.132]) smtp.mail=noreply@glavclub.com; dkim=pass header.i=@glavclub.com
X-Yandex-Suid-Status: 4 1130000036839323
X-Yandex-Spam: 4
X-Yandex-Envelope: aGVsbz1nbGF2Y2x1Yi5jb20KbWFpbF9mcm9tPW5vcmVwbHlAZ2xhdmNsdWIuY29tCnJjcHRfdG89aWx5YUB2YWd1bi5ydQpyZW1vdGVfaG9zdD0xNzYxNDcuc2ltcGxlY2xvdWQucnUKcmVtb3RlX2lwPTg1LjE0My4yMTYuMTMyCg==
X-Yandex-Fwd: NTg2MTU2ODAyNTI1NjQ5OTAwMCwxNjM4MDk1NDU5NjczNDYwOTEyMg==
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [IPv6:::1])
    by glavclub.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 8ED22B8EA2
    for <mail@yandex.ru>; Tue, 26 Nov 2019 07:57:37 +0300 (MSK)
```

```
Received: from mxfront3q.mail.yandex.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])
Received: from 176147.simplecloud.ru (176147.simplecloud.ru [85.143.216.132])
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [IPv6:::1])
```

Последний IP был 127.0.0.1. Но там LMTP (местное хранилище почты), поэтому нужно использовать предпоследний IP `85.143.216.132` для проверки в блек листах.

Правильно я рассуждаю? Может быть есть какие-то правила на этот счет? Что использует spamassassin для этой цели?

Comment: Не знаю что использует spamassasin, но по-моему проверять нужно все. Сам отправитель может добавить столько Received'ов, сколько захочет (в том числе поддельных), и никто не в состоянии помешать ему это сделать.

Comment: @andreymal, может быть. По моей логике, последний `Received: from` добавляется конечным MTA, и это является "лицом" отправителя. Если это опенрелей, чем пользуются спамеры, то тут они и попались, такой релей быстро окажется в блеклисте.